# Android Room multiple embedded fields of same type

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room, android-architecture-components

Let's suppose I have the below model:

```
@Entity
public class Session {
    @Embedded
    Student student;
    @Embedded
    Tutor tutor;
    String location;
    Long timestamp;
}

public class student {
    Person person;
    double rating;
}

public class Tutor {
    Person person;
    double rating;
    double hourlyRate;
}

public class Person {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;

}
```

When building the project, it will tell me that there is a duplicate field "firstName" because both Tutor and Student have the same Person model.

In reality the Person model is way bigger than just a simple firstName and lastName so OverrideAttributes is not a good solution for my case. What can I do to maybe prefix the attribute names depending on the embedded model.

Comment: Just found out that there is a @Embedded(prefix = "foo_") when reading more in the documentation.

Comment: Even if you figured out the `prefix` part, how did you manage to read from the database? Did you create a query in the `Dao` to load those columns? You cant access those columns programmatically.